# What's the best option for starting and stopping an eventmachine server from a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arduino, thin, eventmachine

CORRECTION:

Specifically I'm looking to start and stop an [EventMachine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern#Implementations) (EM) from a Ruby on Rails controller.

(I've been told that 'Thin' would work well for this.)

NOTE:
<del>This EM server is SEPARATE from the [Mongrel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongrel_%28web_server%29) server running the Ruby on Rails application. (The EM server is accepting connections from an Arduino microcontroller.)</del>

Running 'Thin' as the server .. I SHOULD be able to accept both HTTP requests and the Arduino's connections.

```
# Starts Server
def start_control_server
    EventMachine::run {
        @EchoServer = EventMachine::start_server "0.0.0.0", 40013, EchoServer
    }
end

# Attempts ( fails ) to stop server
def stop_control_server
    EventMachine.stop_server(@EchoServer)
end
```

If you're recommending other servers OTHER than a straight-up EventMachine please provide code to execute the above code.

Complete controller code available here: http://pastie.org/1698383

Comment: EventMachine.stop_event_loop 
from the EM docs: "It causes the processing loop to stop executing, which will cause all open connections and accepting servers to be run down and closed."

** not yet verified **

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're not calling start_control_server and stop_control_server inside another controller method. That means your instance variable (@EchoServer) isn't going to exist when you call stop.

One solution might be to store the id returned from start_server in the session. As in

```
  def start_control_server
    session[:em_server_id] = EventMachine::start_server "0.0.0.0", 4000, EchoServer
  end

  def stop_control_server
    EventMachine.stop_server(session[:em_server_id]) if session[:em_server_id]
    session[:em_server_id] = nil
  end
```

Also, if you're running your rails app using thin then you are already inside an eventmachine loop, so you don't need to call EventMachine::run. Calling EventMachine.stop_server doesn't seem to disconnect anything that is already connected but stops any further connections from being established to the specified port.

Hope thats of some use!